# Sentmail To send a URL

Tags: php, email, mailto

I use php to send an email reseting a password.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if($_POST['UserEmail'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['UserEmail'] = "E-mail is required.";
 }
 else
 {
  //whether the UserEmail format is correct
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['UserEmail']))
  {
   //if it has the correct format whether the UserEmail has already exist
   $UserEmail= $_POST['UserEmail'];
   $to = $UserEmail;
   $subject = "Forgotten Password";
   $header = "Change your password using the link below";
   $message = "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=$UserEmail&5832572895237532897523875";
   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   }
  }
?>
```

I want the $message to be a clickable link how do i do this.

This is using WAMPs default mailing system.

cheers

I Have tried adding an anchor tag but that sends the anchor aswell not just the clickable link
using 
`$Message="<a href=http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=James@email.co.uk&5832572895237532897523875>click here</a>"` Doesnt work either any suggestions

Fix Found
basically it was fine just leaving the link in without any anchor tags.

```
$message="http://www.sitename.com/this.php?Username=email@email.com&432941482401284"
```

will display a clickable link inside your email.

Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `anchor` tag to make it clickable and assing it to $message:-

```
$message= "<a href='http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=".$UserEmail."&5832572895237532897523875'>Click Here</a>";
```

Comment: Hello can you help would it be like this    $message = "<a href=http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=$UserEmail&5832572895237532897523875>click here</a>";
   $message .= "";

Comment: This brings back the email like this 
Change your password using the link below

<a href=http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=ja@email.co.uk&5832572895237532897523875>click here</a>

Comment: But that isnt a clickable link ? I would like it to be a clickable link

Comment: //if it has the correct format whether the UserEmail has already exist
   $UserEmail= $_POST['UserEmail'];
   $to = $UserEmail;
   $subject = "Forgotten Password";
   $header = "Change your password using the link below";
   $message = "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=$UserEmail&5832572895237532897523875";
   $message .= "";
   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

Comment: try this $message= "<a href='http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?UserEmail=$UserEmail&5832572895237532897523875'>Click Here</a>";

Comment: Still does not send a clickable link just sends the full text field

Comment: Fix found check the link above thanks for trying i will give you some rep for it

Answer (score 0):

`$header` is the mail-header containing non-display-values.
for example:

```
From: Your Name <you@example.com>\r\n
Reply-To: Max Muster <max@example.com>\r\n
```

(`\r\n` are the escaped characters)
There you also set the content-type:

```
Content-Type: text/html; encoding: utf-8\r\n
```

With this you can use html to design your mail and use `<a>`-tags for your links.

More Information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_Header (Or if you are German: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(E-Mail) )

Everything, that does not belong to the header described in that links, has to be in the message-content, so in your `$message`. That includes your "click on that link below".

For address-checking take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php